# HTML ordered list in UITextView

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am trying to set HTML text with ordered list to an UITextView.

```
NSString *bodyText = "Please follow the below points:<br><ol><li>Point number one.</li><br><li>Point number two.<br><br>Note:<br>There is point to note here.</li><br><li>Point number three.</li></ol>";

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[bodyText dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

self.bodyTextView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Above is the HTML text which I would like to set it to my UITextView. The expected result on my screen should be something like

```
Please follow the below points:

    1. Point number one.

    2. Point number two.

       Note:
       There is point to note here.

    3. Point number three.
```

But, my result I see on screen is,

```
Please follow the below points:

    1. Point number one.
    2.
    3. Point number two.

       Note:
       There is point to note here.
    4.
    5. Point number three.
```

What is the problem? How could I overcome it? I am not supposed to change the HTML text. How would I handle the case from app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is the problem. There should not be any `<br>` tags between the list items. Inside a list item is fine, but not between them.

Remove the two unnecessary `<br>` tags and your output will be correct.

Comment: Then how could new line can be added?

Comment: Which newlines? I'm only talking about the two invalid `<br>` tags between the close `</li>` and the next `<li>`.